# Perl: HOwto split

Tags: perl, split

My code is as follows:

```
VAR DS 0D
    DC    AL1(045),AL2(286),AL2(117),AL2(290)
```

I need to split this and push to my output file in the below 2 formats...

```
format1:
VAR DS  0D
    DC  AL1(045)
    DC  AL2(286)
    DC  AL2(117)
    DC  AL2(290)

format2:
VAR D 
F1  A 045
F2  A 286
F3  A 117
F4  A 290
```

How can I perform this action using Perl.

Comment: What part are you having a problem with? Where's the code you have so far?

Comment: I am fine with splitting and taking to next line.But I am struggling with setting the flags F1,F2,F3,F4.

Comment: We're not a "please write the code for me"-site. Instead this usually works like this: you write some code; you have a problem/question; you show us code you have a problem with and ask specific questions. No, "how do I transform A to B in Perl" does not count as a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am struggling with setting the flags F1,F2,F3,F4.

Once you have extracted the `DC` values,

```
my @dc = qw( AL1(045) AL2(286) AL2(117) AL2(290) );
```

You can use the following:

```
for my $i (0..$#dc) {
   my ($letter, $number) = $dc[$i] =~ /^(.)..\(([0-9]+])\)\z/s
      or die;
   printf("F%-2s %s %s\n", $i, $letter, $number);
}
```